# Editing an AWS lambda function code deployed as container image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I got an AWS lambda function code deployed as container image which was deployed by another developer. I am getting the following message when i try to access that function

```
No code preview available

Your function code is deployed as a container image. The AWS Cloud9 IDE cannot display your code.
```

How is it possible for me to view the code and edit it

Answer (score 0):

Use aws lambda get-function cli command.

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME --query 'Code.Location'
```

```json
"Code": {
  "RepositoryType": "S3",
  "Location": "https://awslambda-us-west-2-tasks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/snapshots/xxxx/yyyy"
}
```

Comment: How can i get the Code.Location ?

Comment: No 'Code.Location' just query command 
You can use cmd without it `aws lambda get-function --function-name YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME`

Comment: Okay. My doubt is how i can edit the code which is deployed as a container image.